# Regular Expression Opposite

Tags: regex

Is it possible to write a regex that returns the converse of a desired result?  Regexes are usually inclusive - finding matches.  I want to be able to transform a regex into its opposite - asserting that there are no matches.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

http://zijab.blogspot.com/2008/09/finding-opposite-of-regular-expression.html states that you should bracket your regex with

```
/^((?!^ MYREGEX ).)*$/
```

, but this doesn't seem to work.  If I have regex

```
/[a|b]./
```

, the string "abc" returns false with both my regex and the converse suggested by zijab,

```
/^((?!^[a|b].).)*$/
```

.  Is it possible to write a regex's converse, or am I thinking incorrectly?

Comment: Which regex package are you using (which language are you working in)?  If your regex package doesn't support a fairly modern PCRE (Perl-compatible RegEx) package, it may be that it is simply misinterpreting Zijab's example (the zero-width negative lookahead).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason your inverted regex isn't working is because of the '`^`' inside the negative lookahead:

```
/^((?!^[ab].).)*$/
      ^            # WRONG
```

Maybe it's different in vim, but in every regex flavor I'm familiar with, the caret matches the beginning of the string (or the beginning of a line in multiline mode).  But I think that was just a typo in the blog entry.

You also need to take into account the semantics of the regex tool you're using.  For example, in Perl, this is true:

```
"abc" =~ /[ab]./
```

But in Java, this isn't:

```
"abc".matches("[ab].")
```

That's because the regex passed to the `matches()` method is implicitly anchored at both ends (i.e., `/^[ab].$/`).

Taking the more common, Perl semantics, `/[ab]./` means the target string contains a sequence consisting of an 'a' or 'b' followed by at least one (non-line separator) character.  In other words, at ANY point, the condition is TRUE.  The inverse of that statement is, at EVERY point the condition is FALSE.  That means, before you consume each character, you perform a negative lookahead to confirm that the character isn't the beginning of a matching sequence:

```
(?![ab].).
```

And you have to examine *every* character, so the regex has to be anchored at both ends:

```
/^(?:(?![ab].).)*$/
```

That's the general idea, but I don't think it's possible to invert *every* regex--not when the original regexes can include positive and negative lookarounds, reluctant and possessive quantifiers, and who-knows-what.

Answer (score 15):

Couldn't you just check to see if there are no matches? I don't know what language you are using, but how about this pseudocode?

```
if (!'Some String'.match(someRegularExpression))
    // do something...
```

If you can only change the regex, then the one you got from your link should work:

```
/^((?!REGULAR_EXPRESSION_HERE).)*$/
```

Comment: Well, that's the problem.  I'm not writing the regexes or the code. I have an app that lets people enter their own regexes, and they need to be either inclusive or exclusive.  I either need to have them enter in another piece of data - inclusive/exclusive, or force them to write them all inclusive or exclusive, using an 'opposite' pattern, if one exists.  This will only be used by programmers, so complexity is not a concern - just possibility.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Then why doesn't this work?
/^((?!REGULAR_EXPRESSION_HERE).)*$/
(Taken from your link.) It works for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can invert the character set by writing a `^` at the start (`[^…]`). So the opposite expression of `[ab]` (match either `a` or `b`) is `[^ab]` (match neither `a` nor `b`).

But the more complex your expression gets, the more complex is the complementary expression too. An example:

You want to match the literal `foo`. An expression, that does match anything else but a string that contains `foo` would have to match either

1. any string that’s shorter than `foo`  (`^.{0,2}$`), or
2. any three characters long string that’s not `foo` (`^([^f]..|f[^o].|fo[^o])$`), or
3. any longer string that does not contain `foo`.

All together this may work:

```
^[^fo]*(f+($|[^o]|o($|[^fo]*)))*$
```

But note: This does only apply to `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this (in python) by using `re.split`, and splitting based on your regular expression, thus returning all the parts that don't match the regex, [how to find the converse of a regex](http://www.technomancy.org/python/strings-that-dont-match-regex/)

Answer (score 2):

In perl you can anti-match with `$string !~ /regex/;`.

Answer (score 1):

With grep, you can use `--invert-match` or `-v`.

Answer (score 0):

Java Regexps have an interesting way of doing this (can test [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)) where you can create a greedy optional match for the string you want, and then match data after it. If the greedy match fails, it's optional so it doesn't matter, if it succeeds, it needs some extra data to match the second expression and so fails.

It looks counter-intuitive, but works.

Eg `(foo)?+.+` matches `bar`, `foox` and `xfoo` but won't match `foo` (or an empty string).

It might be possible in other dialects, but couldn't get it to work myself (they seem more willing to backtrack if the second match fails?)