# Opposite result of a regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this regex

```
^(\d+)/\1$
```

that matches strings like

```
1/1
2/2
5/5
```

I want to get the inverse result of this regex. I browsed the net and [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850907/regular-expression-opposite) and found that

```
^((?!(\d+)/\1.).)*$
```

should do the trick, but it doesn't.

Could anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: The inverse result? That means **not** matching these kind of strings?

Comment: Can't you just test `!match(your_regex)`? Or do you want to match patterns such as `1/2` and `2/3`?

Comment: Yeah, Felix - I need strings that don't look like that. @Joao I can't code it, it's a filter inside a datatable. Edit: yes - I need such strings - 1/2 and 2/3 but NOT 2/2 and 5/5 type strings.

Comment: I have a predictable input: all strings have the format number/number.

Comment: @Tool: I see, take at look at my answer and see if it suits your needs. Since all your strings have that precise format, it's the exact opposite of the above regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^(\d+)\/(?!\1$)\d+$/
```

This will match `2/3` or `1/10`, but not `1/1` and `2/2`, et cetera. In other words, it will match only when the first part of the fraction is different from the second part.

Comment: This leaves out 0/10 for me. I need to match 0/10 aswell (condition: number on the left has to be different from the number on the right, and there's no exception to input - they'll always be numbers, so I don't have to worry about that). Edit: it also doesn't show 3/10.