# RegularExpressionValidator - validate that a string does NOT match an expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression (for use in an ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator) so that:

If the string to be validated contains the letter A followed by the letter B, validation should fail.

If the string to be validated contains the letter F followed by any of W, X, Y, Z or any digit, validation should fail.

I've come up with this

```
(AB)|(F(W|X|Y|Z|[0-9]))
```

but as far as I can tell, validation will succeed if the input does match that expression.

What do I need to do to make the validation fail if the input does not match that expression?

Thanks very much,

David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are for

```
(?!.*AB)(?!.*F[WXYZ\d])
```

fails on these strings. It doesn't match any text yet (which should be sufficient if all you want to do is check whether there is a match or not), so the match result will always be an empty string

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
A[^B]|F[^WXYZ0-9]|[^AF].
```

- an A followed by anything except a B, or
- an F followed by anything excepty W,X,Y,Z or digit, or
- something other that A or F followed by any single character

Note that this would also match "A$" or "@@". If you only want to match "one letter followed by one letter or digit", then use this:

```
A[AC-Z0-9]|F[A-V]|[B-EG-Z][A-Z0-9]
```

Regex is better at positive matches.

Note that for the regex validator the entire string must match (if just a substring matches, the validator reports a validation failure)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the logical not operator provided by your programming language to negate the result returned by the match operation there is no need to modify your regex.

Edit: In case the above is not an option please look at these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-to-inverse-match-with-regex), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957379/invert-match-with-regexp) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850907/regular-expression-opposite/850918#850918).

Comment: True, but that wouldn't work in a regex validator, you would need a CustomValidator for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a match against this regex

```
^(?!^.*?AB)(?!^.*?F[WXYZ\d]).*$
```

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/ug0Hp0njmX) a working example. Basically it means "find all the strings except the strings containing AB with an arbitrary number of characters before and after and except those containing an F followed by W,X,Y,Z or a digit". Info at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) link provided in Tim Pietzcker's answer