# RegEx is not accepting spaces

Tags: regex, whitespace

Hi I have a requirement where bunch of expressions should not be accepted which includes white spaces as well.

Below are the expressions.

1. `PA#N<number>.<number>#ADP<number>` e.g. `PA#N1.1#ADP1`
2. `PA#N<number>.<number>,<number>.<number>#ADP<number>` e.g. `PA#N1.1,1.2#ADP1,2`
3. `PA#N<number>#ADP<number>` e.g. `PA#N1#ADP4`
4. `PA#N<number>,<number>#ADP<number>` e.g. `PA#N1,2#ADP4`
5. `PA#N<number>,<number>.<number>,<number>#ADP<number>` e.g `PA#N1,2.1,3#ADP1`
6. `PA#N<number>,<number>.<number>-<number>#ADP<number>` e.g. `PA#N1.1-3#ADP1`
7. `PA#N<number>,<number>.<number>-<number>.<number>#ADP<number>` e.g. `PA#N1.1- 3.2#ADP1,2`
8. `PA#NUAL,AZ,AN#FOP<number>`
9. `PA#N1.1-2.1,3.1#ADP#PUSH`
10. `PA*N1.1*ADP`

and if it is having any spaces at `PA#<space>N<space>1<space>1#ADP` also not acceptable, but `PA#N1.1...#5#SOME TEXT` (the `SOME TEXT` part after last '#' with free text with free spaces are acceptable).

`PA*` also not acceptable.

For all these the above conditions to be satisfied , I created a regex

```
PA(?!\*$)(?!([#*].*\s+).*)(?!(\*N(\d+(\.\d+)?,?)+)$)(?!([#*](U.*|T.*|(N\d+\.?\d*)-(\d+\.?\d*)|(N(\d+(\.\d+)?,?)+))){1,3}[#*]ADP).*
```

All the above conditions are matched with the above regex, only thing missing is  `PA#N1.1#5#FREE TEXT` (if we give any space between `FREE<SPACE>TEXT` then it is not accepting.

If we don't give any space between `FREE TEXT` like `FREETEXT` then that matches with above regex.

Could anybody help to find my mistake and what would be the correct expression? I have been struggling with this 2 days.

Comment: If I am not mistaken your second lookahead should actually be positive and not negative.

Comment: select a correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest two things to simplify the solution:

1. Assume that all the combinations between `PA#N` and `#ADP` can be described as a series of 1 to 6 numbers delimited by ether `.`, or `,`, or `-` and optionally surrounded by spaces. This can be expressed by the `\s*\d+\s*(?:[\.,-]\s*\d+\s*){0,5}`. I'm not sure if this assumption is acceptable for you, but if it is, this would simplify the the regex a lot. If the assumption is not acceptable, I provided a link to the extended regex in the end of the answer.
2. Write a pattern to match all the strings you have to *exclude* and then invert it using the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/850918/4295017). In brief it looks like this: `/^((?!INVERTED_PATTERN).)*$/`

The expression in this case would be:

```
^((?!      # This and the final line allow invert the regex condition

PA(?:
    \*(?:N\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s*\*ADP)?    # match the asterisk cases
  | \#\s*N\s*\d+\s*                      # or the hash cases
        (?:[\.,-]\s*\d+\s*){0,5}
    \#ADP\s*(?:\d|\#PUSH)
  | \#NUAL,AZ,AN\#FOP\d                  # or the 'UAL,AZ,AN' literal
)

).)*$
```

Note: this regex requires the `x` modifier to be used.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bY4xU6/3

If the first assumption is not acceptable, you may use more elaborated regex from here: https://regex101.com/r/oD8uG7/1