# Route constraints call the controller method if its not any image

Tags: c#, regex, routes

I'm terrible at regex, but anybody can help here.
We have redirect all path to one method but we don't want it if path has any images extension.

I have tried but current code is totally fail.

```
           routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultCMS",
                url: "{*paths}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    paths = UrlParameter.Optional
                },
                constraints: new { paths = @".*\.(jpeg|gif|jpg|png)(/.)?)" } // this regex only allow if path has this extension.
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: to match the opposite of a pattern refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850907/regular-expression-opposite)

This regex should match any string that ends with ".{extension}" where {extension} is placeholder for one of the extensions you listed:

^.*\.(jpeg|gif|jpg|png)$

Comment: Hi elder S, Thank for answer but what if I dont want to match any string if it has 
.{extension}

Comment: So you want to match all strings that don't follow the pattern?

Comment: Yes right, Match all string that doesn't follow the pattern.